# Is the routes Dispatcher broken in CherryPy for Mac?

Tags: python, cherrypy

Is CherryPy broken? I just set it up and tried to use the routes dispatcher but it has an import error, my code is as follows:

```
import cherrypy

mapper = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jwesonga/environments/cherrypy/lib/python2.6/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.6.egg/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 463, in __init__
    import routes
ImportError: No module named routes
```

I'm on a Mac and I tried both 3.2.2 and 3.0 using virtualenv for the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution but there's greater than 99% probability that the answer to the question "Is X broken?" or "Is this a bug in X?" is "no".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have successfully used CherryPy with the routes dispatcher under OS X.

The error you've shown is:

```
ImportError: No module named routes
```

This is pretty clear -- Python can't find the `routes` modules.  Have you installed it?  This is not part of CherryPy, it's a separate module that you will need to install.  If you're using MacPorts, you should be able to:

```
port install py-routes
```

(Or `py25-routes` or `py26-routes` depending on which Python you're using).  If you're using virtualenv, you can simply run:

```
easy_install routes
```

Comment: thanks @larsks the assumption is always that the installation will pull any and all dependencies...now I know something I didn't..

Comment: yeah, it's a tightrope sometimes. CherryPy integrates with so many other pieces of software that aren't really "dependencies" unless you choose to use them in *your* project. Sorry you got bit by that.

Comment: You should put the url to the Routes project for the download links